# Case class extending another class loses its toString?

Tags: scala, case-class

```
class Bar { override def toString() = "Bar" }
case class Foo(s: String) extends Bar
Foo("bar") // "Bar"
```

Why doesn't `Foo` get it's `toString` generated? Is it a bug or is there actually a reason? Is there any way to "get it back" (is there a default implementation somewhere that works for case classes perhaps)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a bug, it is the specified behavior that the case class gets it's implementation from the parent instead of generating one of it's own.

It's mentioned in the [Scala Specification §5.3.2](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#case-classes):

> Every case class implicitly overrides some method definitions of class
>   `scala.AnyRef` unless a definition of the same method is already given
>   in the case class itself or a concrete definition of the same method
>   is given in some base class of the case class different from AnyRef.
>   In particular:
>
> - Method `toString`: String returns a string representation which contains the name of the class and its elements.

I think the only way to make this work would be to explicitly override `toString` again in `Foo` yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I get it, that I have to override `toString` ... The question is _what_ do I override it to? Is there a function somewhere I can call to get the default behavior, or do I have to actually repeat the whole implementation?

Comment: @Dima You mean: "Is there an API to provide a case class and get a string representation of that class"? If so, not sure, perhaps looking at the decompiled `toString` on an arbitrary case class, though I'd argue it's probably some compiler implementation detail.

Comment: @Dima Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718506/scala-how-to-print-case-classes-like-pretty-printed-tree

Answer (score 2):

To reproduce the default implementation, you can use

```
override def toString() = productPrefix + productIterator.mkString("(", ", ", ")")
```

I seem to remember this method being somewhere in the standard library, but couldn't find it just now. Of course this will be less efficient than implementing it manually e.g. as `productPrefix + "(" + field1 + ", " + ...`, but this method is not going to be a hotspot in most cases, and it gives less opportunity for error.

Comment: Does it work for nested structures? i.e case class inside a case class?

Comment: It'll use the `toString` method of that case class, which will again be either default or implemented by you, and it shouldn't matter which (as far as I am aware). Of course, if you want pretty-printing as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718506/scala-how-to-print-case-classes-like-pretty-printed-tree, things get more complicated, but the standard implementation doesn't do that.

Comment: I think the method you were trying to remember is `ScalaRuntime._toString(this)` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27467406/349831) :)